# Android ConstraintLayout not centering view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to center an ImageView within a ConstraintLayout as seen below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_busy"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the result:

[image]

I'm currently using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4`.

How do I center the ImageView?

Comment: I don't see the issue with the code you posted. I could center the image view to the center of the constraint layout with the code you posted.

Comment: refresh design view or check with run build.. code is correct only

Comment: @RohitPadma what version of Android Studio did you validate this in? I'm on 4.0.2.

Comment: @RyanPierce - I'm using android studio 4.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from Android Studio 4.0.2 to 4.1.1 resolved this issue. Invalidating caches and restarting did not resolve the issue while on Android Studio 4.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this is a problem when rendering the design because the code is correct. Make sure you have implement `ConstraintLayout` in your `build.gradle`. If this still happens try restarting your `Android Studio`. Go to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

Comment: Unfortunately, I did all of this before posting the question.

Comment: and the result still the same? What other steps have you taken?